# Is it possible to write text in an arc shape using iText

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I want to write some text in the arc shape as shown in the image.

Does iText for java provides some functionality to do this?Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to do that with iText. However, with some simple math, you can define the path, and then the position and angle of each letter. Then, use this [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=246) (taken from the [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book/) book) as an inspiration on how to draw each character at the desired position/angle.